# Separating (grouping) different crop types that are phenologically the same

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, image-classification, agriculture

I have a bean farm plants UAV images, but they are different crop types, and others that are phenological the same. Can I cluster the plant fields using the UAV images? I cannot figure out from the UAV images details of the crop type, just colors...

I am using QGIS... and I am able to program in Python if needed.

Update (19/8/2021): The idea is for example: I have 20 plant fields, seen as "rectangles" each one. The 1st "rectangle" has bean variety no1, the 2nd "rectangle" has the bean variety no2, the 3rd "rectangle" has the bean variety no3 (but phenological is identical to that of bean variety no1). The 4th "rectangle" has the bean variety no4, the 5th rectangle has the bean variety no5 (but phenological is identical to that of of bean variety no2). So, how do I say: "rectangle" no1 ---> this variety, "rectangle" no2 --> that variety ... "rectangle" no20 ----> x variety, by using UAV/drone .tif images...??

(I have edited the question...can you open it again ? Does any admin see that? Am I suppose to open a new thread?)

Comment: Are you asking about image segmentation? For example using GRASS: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/i.segment.html

Comment: I am studying the link..

Comment: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/wxGUI.iclass.html    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7OQ5BLT8Wo  or using python: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373720/performing-supervised-classification-on-sentinel-images/374726#374726

Comment: @BERA: What do I put in the python code in link you posted, here: `pointfile = 'C:\GIS\Machine_learning\Landuse\Samples_line_dens8m_extractverts.shp'`  ? Also the python code is irrelevant to QGIS, right? I mean,  I do not use the python code along with the QGIS, right?